# Cast method parameter to class. Interface related

Tags: c#, .net

I have three classes that implement an interface and I need one Method that accepts such an object. The interface for example:

```
public interface IFoo {
  void DoThis();
}
```

One of the classes:

```
public class Bar: IFoo {
  public void DoThis();
}
```

And the method I would like to have, i.e. on a form:

```
private void DoStuff(object o){
  o.DoThis();
}
```

How can I achieve that I can call the `DoThis()` method in the `DoStuff(object o)` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your method like so::

```
    private void DoStuff(IFoo o){
          o.DoThis();
    }
```

Otherwise you can't use the `IFoo` interface members.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void DoStuff<T>(T o) where T : IFoo
{
    o.DoThis();
}
```

OR

```
private void DoStuff(object o) 
{
    IFoo foo = o as IFoo;
    if (foo != null)
    {
        foo.DoThis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private void DoStuff(IFoo o){
    o.DoThis();
}
```

Or this:

```
private void DoStuff(object o){
    IFoo ifoo;
    try
    {
        ifoo = (IFoo)o;
    }
    catch(InvalidCastException ice)
    {
        /* whatever "this isn't IFoo" logic you want here */
        throw; 
    }
    ifoo.DoThis();
}
```

Comment: There are generally better options than getting an InvalidCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if the signature can't change:

```
private void DoStuff(object o){
  IFoo foo = (IFoo) o;    
  foo.DoThis();
}
```